# Writing Math: Is using both $e^x$ and $\exp(x)$ ok for longer works?

Tags: soft-question, notation, article-writing

I wanted to know what you guys think about mixing both notations for the exponential function $e^x$(for simple argument and to save space for larger equations) and $\exp(x)$ (for more complicated arguments) in one single work.

Comment: I don't mind two different notations popping up if there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this done before. The one thing to note is that if the reader sees both $e^x$ and $\operatorname{exp}(x)$, they might wonder if the notational difference is marking some difference in meaning. This, of course, can be solved by making it clear that these are, in fact, the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I discovered that I've mixed the notation in a work on Lie Groups.

It was unfortunated because I than realized that I could use $exp(X)$ for the application between the Lie Algebra and the Lie Group, while using $e^X$ for the proper matrix exponential and then I could conclude in a theorem that $exp(X)=e^X$. 
It would have been a great theorem...